# Show that some group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_n}$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

> If $G$ has order $4$ and has an element of order $4$, then $G$ is
>   isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_4}$.

Can someone briefly explain why this is true? I understand that $|G| = 4$, but I don't understand why, if one element has order $4$, then the two sets are necessarily isomorphic.

Comment: They both "look" the same. The elements of each all have the same form... what form am I talking about? Figure out what the (or "a") isomorphism is. More generally, any two cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic. Can you see that?

Comment: @anon if an element in $G$ has order $4$, why does this mean that $G$ is cyclic?

Comment: Because the definition of a cyclic group is (more or less) that there is some element $x$ such that the powers of $x$ give you every element in the group.

Comment: Joel, if $A\subseteq B$ and $B$ is finite and $|A|=|B|$, then $A=B$. Apply here with $A=\langle g\rangle$ and $B=G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me expound upon Krjin's answer. Your group $G$ is of the form $\{e,a,b,c\}$. Suppose $a$ is the element of order $4$. Then there are a couple of options: $a^2 = b$ or $a^2 = c$. Without loss of generality, assume $a^2 = b$, then $b^2 = e$.

From here, $ab = a^3$. This cannot be $a$ or $b$ either and so $ab = c$. Hence $c^2 = a^6 \neq e$ and $c^3 = a^9 \neq e$, giving $c^4 = e$. In recap:

1. $a^4 = e$
2. $b^2 = e$
3. $c^4 = e$

In $\Bbb Z_4$, there are two elements of order $4$ and one element of order $2$ and your group $G$ is cyclic with these same properties. Do you see how to proceed?

Comment: The ord(0) = 1, right? Since 0^1 = 0 mod 4? But how do we find the ord(1)? Since 1^x = 0 mod 4 has no solutions?

Comment: @Joel In $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ the group operation is addition, not multiplication, so $g^n=e$ translated into **additive** notation means $ng\equiv 0$ mod $4$. The order of $1$ is the least positive integer $n$ such that $n\cdot1\equiv0$ mod $4$, which of course is $n=4$.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to write out a multiplication table for a group with 4 elements (lets call it $G = \{e, a, b, c\} $) then you will see that there are only two possible multiplication tables. 
So, up to isomorphism there are only two different groups of order $4$. One of these has an element of order $4$, the other doesnt. Now its left to you to check if the group with the element of order $4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Comment: If an element in $G$ has order $4$, then we know that there is some element $x \in G$ such that $(x^4 = 1) \mod 4$?

Comment: Well, no, thats if your $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}_n$. If an element $x\in G$ has order $4$, then it just means that $x^4=e$, and $x^n\neq 4$ if $n = 1, 2, 3$

Comment: How do we determine the value of $e$?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I used $e$ where others may use $1$, as the neutral element of the group $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $1$. If you have a group $G$ of order $n$ with an element $g$ of order $n$, then $g$ is a generator for the group. So, the natural map to consider is just $g\leadsto 1$. Note that the only difference here is that you will be working with exponents in $G$ and addition in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Note that since each member of $G$ is of the form $g^m$ for some $m\in \mathbb{Z}$, the homomorphism $G\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is completely determined by $g\leadsto 1$, so you just have to check that it's 1-1 and onto, which is easy.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a group $G$ is cyclic if it contains an element whose powers generate $G$, i.e. if $\exists x \in G$ such that $\{x^n: n \in \mathbb{Z} \} = G$.  Since $G$ has order 4 and contains an element $a$ of order 4, the elements $a,a^2,a^3$ and $1$ are distinct and exhaust all the elements of $G$.  Thus, $G$ is the cyclic group $\langle a \rangle$.  Any two cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic: for eg, $G=\langle a \rangle$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4  = \langle 1 \rangle$ are isomorphic via the map $a^k \mapsto k$.